# problema con tema dark de sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, css3, sweetalert2, alert

Soy nueva en esto y no se como poner el tema oscuro para mi alerta. copie como dice la documentación pero no pasa nada

`npm install --save sweetalert2 @sweetalert2/theme-dark`

Esto lo instale en la terminal de visual studio code y pareciera haber quedado bien

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@sweetalert2/theme-dark/dark.css">

<script src="sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Estos los pegue en el html, en el head.

He intentado pero no he podido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código donde usas SweetAlert

Comment: hola rene, gracias, lo agrege como captura de pantalla

Comment: el codigo siempre pegado no como imagen

Comment: Antes que te agarren a negativos por el formato de la pregunta, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

el link y el script correctos son estos sin la necesidad de instalar el npm son los siguientes

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Así quedaría un ejemplo resumido de tu código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mi primera página web</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="mostrar()">mostrar</button>

    <script>
        function mostrar() {
            swal.fire({
                position: 'top-end',
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your work has been saved',

            })
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias claudio, me sirvio. Te puedo preguntar de donde los sacaste los codigos correctos?

Comment: Desde acá https://sweetalert2.github.io/#themes  tienen los link al CDN para no necesitar instalaciones